# T-SQL queries in Azure Log Analytics Workspaces?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring, kql

Azure Data Explorer supposedly [supports T-SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/t-sql#querying-from-kustoexplorer-with-t-sql):

> The Kusto.Explorer tool supports T-SQL queries to Kusto. To instruct Kusto.Explorer to execute a query, begin the query with an empty T-SQL comment line (--).

However, I can't get this to work in a [Log Analytics Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace).

For instance, this Kusto query works fine and returns results:

```
ContainerInstanceLog_CL
| where Message has "Hamlet"
| limit 500
```

But any attempt to use T-SQL (with a leading empty comment line) ...

```
--
SELECT * FROM ContainerInstanceLog_CL
```

...fails with

```
Query could not be parsed at '-' on line [1,1]

Token: -
Line: 1
Position: 1
```

Are T-SQL queries not supported in Log Analytics Workspaces?

Comment: Log Analytics Workspaces supports only Kusto as of now. You can further integrate it with power BI for better analytics options.

Comment: @roshaga, please add your comment as answer:).

Comment: Thanks will add it as an answer! Still learning the ways here.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you cannot run T-SQL queries in Azure Log Analytics Workspaces.

[image]

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

---

[T-SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/t-sql#querying-from-kustoexplorer-with-t-sql) run on the Azure Data Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Writing my comment as an answer as suggested.

Log Analytics Workspaces supports only Kusto as of now. You can further integrate it with power BI for better analytics options.